# Solve $31x + 21y = 1010$ using modular arithmetic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

x and y must be positive integer solutions
I have the following:

$$18 = 0x + 21y \text{ mod } 31$$
$$2 = 31x + 0y \text{ mod } 21$$

and 
$$y=\frac{18}{21} \text{ mod }31$$
$$x=\frac{31}{2} \text{ mod }21$$

How do I solve for x and y, to put them in integer form?

Comment: We could use the full machinery of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. Or else observe that $(-2)(31)+(3)(21)=1$.

Comment: My answer got a bit longish. If you want details, grab a book on elementary number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you determine 1/21 (mod 31)?  It must be the integer, x, such that 21x= 1 (mod 31).  That equation is the same as 21x= 1+ 31k for some integer, k, so gives Diophantine equation 21x- 31k= 1.  I would solve that by noting that 21 divides into 31 once with remainder 10: 31- 21= 10.  And then 10 divides into 21 twice with remainder 1: 21- 2(10)= 1.  Replace that "10" with "31- 21": 21- 2(31- 21)= 3(21)- 2*(31)= 1.  So one solution to 21x- 31k= 1 is x= 3, y= 2.  That is, 1/21 (mod 31) is 2 and so 18/21 (mod 31) is 2*18= 36= 5 (mod 31).

Similarly, 1/2 (mod 21) is the integer, y, such that 2y= 1 (mod 21) and it should be easy to see, without any calculation, that y= 11 (so 2y= 22= 1 (mod 21)).  Then 31/2 (mod 21) is 11(31)= 341=  5 (mod 21).

However, 31(5)+ 21(5)= 155+ 105= 260, not 1010 so your original reduction to two separate equations is incorrect.

Here is how I would solve "31x+ 21y= 1010".  First, note that 21 divides into 31 once, with remainder 10: 31- 21= 10.  Now, 10 divides into 21 twice with remainder 1: 21- 2(10)= 1.  Replacing that "10" with "31- 21", 21- 2(31- 21)= 3(21)- 2(31)= 1.  Multiplying by 1010, 3030(21)- 2020(31)= 1010.  So one solution to 31x+ 21y= 1010 is x= -2020, y= 3030.  But it is easy to see that, for any integer, k, x= -2020+ 21k, y= 3030- 31k is also a solution: 31(-2020+ 21k)+ 2(3030- 31k)= 31(-2020)+ 2(3030)- (31)(21)k+ (21)(31)k= 1010.  In order that x be positive, k must be at least 97.  Taking k= 97, x= -2020+ 21(97)= 17 while y= 3030- 31(97)= 23 and, clearly, any larger value for k would make y negative.

Comment: why did you do $31(-2020+ 21k)+ 2(3030- 31k)$ as opposed to $31(-2020+ 21k)+ 21(3030- 31k)$

Comment: and how did you deduce $k=97$

Answer (score 3):

**The Problem**

Your problem can be treated as a linear Diophantine equation in integer values $x$ and $y$, where one restricts to solutions with positive values.

Like in the case of continous linear equations, one can solve this by

- finding the general homogenous solution $(x_h, y_h)$, solving for $a\, x_h + b\, y_h = 0$ and
- finding one particular solution $(x_p, y_p)$, solving for $a\, x_p + b\, y_p = c \quad (*)$

The general solution is then $(x, y) = (x_h + x_p, y_h + y_p)$.

**Solving the Homogenous Equation**

Key ingredient is using the extended Euclidean algorithm to solve
$$
d = \gcd(a,b) \\
s\, a + t\, b = d
$$
for $s, t \in \mathbb{Z}$. One then sets
$$
a = d\, a' \quad b = d\, b'
$$
so we have
$$
d = \gcd(a, b) = \gcd(d\, a', d\, b') = |d| \gcd(a', b') \Rightarrow \gcd(a', b') = 1
$$
using the distributive property of the greatest common denominator. So we arrive at
$$
a' x = -b' y \wedge \gcd(a', b') = 1
$$
which can be solved by
$$
(x_h, y_h) = (k\, b', -k\ a') \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})
$$
In your case we have
$$
a = 31, \quad b = 21, \quad c = 1010
$$
The extended Eucledian algorithm gives

```
i: 0, q: 1, r: 31, s: 1, t: 0
i: 1, q: 1, r: 21, s: 0, t: 1
i: 2, q: 1, r: 10, s: 1, t: -1
i: 3, q: 2, r: 1, s: -2, t: 3
i: 4, q: 10, r: 0, s: 21, t: -31
```

thus
$$
d = 1, \quad s = -2, \quad t = 3
$$
Check:
$$
(-2)\, 31 + 3\, 21 = -62 + 63 = 1 
$$
So the homogenous solution is
$$
(x_h, y_h) = (21\, k, -31\, k) \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})
$$

**Solving the Inhomogenous Equation**

It turns out that
$$
(x_p, y_p) = \left(\frac{c}{d} s, \frac{c}{d} t\right)
$$
is a particular solution of the (inhomogenous) equation $(*)$. It requires $d \mid c$.

In your case $1\mid 1010$ and this particular solution is $(x_p, y_p) = (-2020, 3030)$. Check:
$$
31 \, (-2020) + 21 \cdot 3030 = 1010 
$$
So all integer solutions are
$$
(x, y) = (21\, k - 2020, -31\, k + 3030) \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})
$$

**Restricting to Positive Integers**

Assuming positive integers are those $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $k > 0$, we can restrict the above solutions to:
$$
21 \, k - 2020 > 0 \iff \\
21 \, k > 2020 \iff \\
k > 2020 / 21 = 96.19\cdots
$$
and
$$
-31 \, k + 3030 > 0 \iff \\
31 \, k < 3030 \iff \\
k < 3030/31 = 97.74\cdots
$$
This leaves one solution for $k = 97$, translating into
$$
(x, y) = (17, 23)
$$
Check:
$$
31\cdot 17 + 21 \cdot 23 = 1010
$$

**Relation to Modular Arithmetic**

Equation $(*)$ can be rewritten as
$$
a\, x = c + b\, (-y)
$$
So we could go for the linear congruence
$$
a\, x \equiv c \pmod b
$$
Similar
$$
b\, y = c + a\, (-x)
$$
leads to
$$
b\, y \equiv c \pmod a
$$
Here this would be
$$
31\, x \equiv 1010 \pmod {21} \\
21\, y \equiv 1010 \pmod {31}
$$
as linear congrences or
$$
31\, x \bmod 21 = 1010 \bmod 21 = 2\\
21\, y \bmod 31 = 1010 \bmod 31 = 18
$$
using the remainder operation.

There exists an algorithm to solve linear congruences $a\,x \equiv b \pmod c$ for solutions $x$, but I would have to look it up. It has similiar ingredients like the above algorithm for solving linear diophantine equations, as expected.